# Datagridview shall disappear when clicking on the Form in the background

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drop-down-menu, datagridview

As described in the title, I have a Form with a Datagridview on the front. The datagridview is smaller than my form in the back and I want the Datagridview to disappear whenever I click anywhere else but the Datagridview.

My code looks like this:

```
this.dataGridView1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.focus);
```

and the Eventhandler is defined like this:

```
private void focus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     if(dataGridView1.Focused == false)
     {
         dataGridView1.Visible = false;
     }
}
```

My problem is that my Datagridview only disappears when a new event in my form is activated but not when I click for example in a textbox on my form.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You want your datagrid to become invisible when it loses focus ? Or what is your question ?

Comment: @GuidoG 12 Yes exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Leave` event will not raise if you click on `Form`, or a `ToolStripButton`, `PictureBox` or any other non-selectable control.

If you expect a behavior like a dropdown, you can host `DataGridView` in a `ToolStripControlHost` and show it using a `ToolStripDropDown`. This way when you click anywhere outside the `DataGridView, it will disappear. It will act like a dropdown menu. Also the grid can be larger than your form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.Margin = new Padding(0);
    var host = new ToolStripControlHost(this.dataGridView1);
    this.dataGridView1.MinimumSize = new Size(200, 100);
    host.Padding = new Padding(0);
    var dropdown = new ToolStripDropDown();
    dropdown.Padding = new Padding(0);
    dropdown.Items.Add(host);
    dropdown.Show(button1, 0,button1.Height);
}
```

[image]

***Important Note:*** It's an example. It's better to pay attention to disposing of objects in a real world application. For example, use just a single `ToolStripdropDown` and dispose it when closing the form.

Comment: I tried your solution statement but with dropdown.Show() I got an error message telling me: Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'. Could the problem be that I tried the whole thing with clicking on a label?

Comment: It worked, I just needed to use a control as a reference point, for example a groupbox or, as in your example, a button. My false was that I thought a label to be a control.

Comment: Great! but you can also show the dropdown without using a reference control. Take a look at other overloads of `Show` method.

Answer (score 1):

Change the event handler assigning to:

```
this.dataGridView1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(fokussiert);
```

Worked for me when focusing on a textbox

Comment: The `Leave` will not raise if you click on `Form`, or a `ToolStripButton`, `PictureBox` or any other non-selectable control.

Comment: @JRoller it did not change anything for me. Where did you define this Eventhandler? Because I defined it in my designer.

Answer (score 0):

you want your dgv also to disapear when you click on your textbox? is that what you mean?

```
   private void dataGridView1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Visible = false;        
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Visible = false;
    }
```