# How to put control in temporary layer in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, user-controls, contextmenu

I have my own user control created. When I click certain button on my form, I want to display my user control. But **I don't want it to be displayed permanently** by something like this:

```
uc.Visible = true;
```

and then hide it again:

```
uc.Visible = false;
```

I want my user control to behave like context menu. When I right-click something, my context menu is shown and then **I don't care how to hide my context menu**. It is hidden automatically:

- when I click some button,
- when I move my window,
- when my window loses focus
- etc.

**How can I achieve this behavior for my user control?**

Comment: [Datagridview shall disappear when clicking on the Form in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38702654/3110834)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little ugly, but I've had some success inheriting from `ToolStripDropDown`, which then contains arbitrary content via a `ToolStripControlHost`. Pass your content (UserControl, Panel, or some other container) to the contructor of `ToolStripControlHost` and add this to `ToolStripDropDown.Items`.

The two ugly parts are:

- It may not autosize itself well, so be prepared to handle sizing yourself. The easiest way is to set `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` of the `ToolStripDropDown` to the size of the contents. Also there is also no inbuilt way for users to resize the window, so you will have to implement this as well if needed.
- Some controls do not behave well inside the `ToolStripDropDown`. As soon as they take focus the entire thing things you've clicked elsewhere and it disappears. Examples are `ComboBox` and `DateTimePicker`. You can get around this by calling `SuspendMenuMode` on and `ResumeMenuMode` on the *internal class* `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripManager+ModalMenuFilter`. You will need to find this type and invoke these two methods using reflection.

The following resources may be of additional help:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-wrap-a-windows-forms-control-with-toolstripcontrolhost
- http://www.codeproject.com/cs/miscctrl/simplepopup.asp