# How can I place object outside of panel in same place?

Tags: .net, winforms

[image]

If I move ☘️운동일기 label to location which option panel located,
[image]

☘️운동일기 label move inside of option panel! But I want to ☘️운동일기 label's parents would be not panel but window.

[image]

Comment: It appears that in both of your screenshots that the label's parents are the window. What are you asking?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38703523/3110834) for example.

Comment: Move it somewhere that is clearly outside of the panel and then change the position in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing that on design mode, when you move the control, you must put the mouse cursor outside the panel when dragging the label.If you move the label with the cursor pointing to the half that stay inside the panel, Visual Studio interpret label is inside the panel.

Comment: And I edited Designer.cs InitializeComponent function directly. Anyway... thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it will help you.